# Specifying the IP address to be used when connecting to an instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an application that was compiled with a hard-coded connection string (using the server's IP address '192.168.40.201' and not the server name) to an SQL Server.

A backup of the database has been restored on a stand-alone machine with no working network adapter and I would wish to be able to connect to this machine's SQL server using the IP address specified in the connection string of the application.

Is there any way to specify that the IP address to be used for this particular instance is '192.168.40.201'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [How to setup and use a SQL Server alias](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1620/how-to-setup-and-use-a-sql-server-alias/)

Excerpts below:

> **Problem**
>
> I have an application that has a specified database connection that I
>   either can't or don't want to change. However, I need to move the
>   database to a new server. How can I do this easily without breaking
>   other things that maybe using this connection and/or database?
>
> **Solution**
>
> By using an alias, we can keep the application configuration the same,
>   but tell the operating system to look somewhere else for the database.
>   One proviso is that once an alias is created, it is set at the
>   operating system level. That means if we have two applications which
>   connect to MySQLServer on that computer, once the alias is created,
>   both will be re-pointed based on the alias. You can create an alias
>   using one of two utilities:
>
> - SQL Server Configuration Manager
> - SQL Server Client Network Utility
>
> **SQL Server Configuration Manager**
>
> Let's start by looking at how to do it using SQL Server Configuration
>   Manager. In the left pane of SQL Server Configuration Manager, if you
>   expand the SQL Native Client Configuration folder, there is a
>   subfolder called Aliases (see Figure 1). If we click on this
>   subfolder, we'll see any aliases that have been defined for the system
>   shown in the right pane. In most cases, there won't be any defined. To
>   create a new alias, right-click on Aliases and choose New Alias...
>   from the pop-up menu.

**Figure 1:**

[image]

> A dialog window comes up (Figure 2) which allows us to specify our new
>   alias. In the Alias Name property, you specify the name the
>   application uses. For instance, if it connects to a SQL Server called
>   MyOldServer, that's what you enter in here. You can also enter an
>   alias that appears to point to a named instance, such as
>   MyOldServer\MyInstance. You can then specify the server where the
>   database really is, to include configuring the protocol, the server
>   name, and the port. Clicking the OK button will create the alias. In
>   the case of Figure 2, I'm creating an alias called MyOldServer which
>   points to my local server's default instance.

**Figure 2:**

[image]

> You should now see the new alias listed in the right pane (Figure 3).

[image]

> The next step is to test the connection. You can do so quickly by
>   either creating and testing a Data Source Name (DSN), or if you have
>   the SQL Server client tools installed, by using SQL Server Management
>   Studio (SSMS). I'll do so using SSMS. Figure 4 shows the dialog window
>   to open a new connection to a database engine. For Server name:, enter
>   in the alias you specified. In the example we called the alias
>   OldServerName, so that's what we'll use here.
>
> **Figure 4:**

[image]

> If the alias is pointed correctly to the new location, a successful
>   connection should be established. In SSMS, I was opening a new
>   connection for Object Explorer. Figure 5 shows that the connection was
>   successfully made using the alias. Note that as far as SSMS is
>   concerned, the server name is the alias.
>
> **Figure 5:**

[image]

Comment: I'm awfully grateful for your answer. Totally solved my problem. Thanks a million